# How to edit the default asp.netcore error tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

i am currently trying to make a simple Ticket System and i am using the provided tag helpers from asp.net.
I have a submit form that gets the user data and send it to the database.

```
 <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="ProjectName"></label>
        <input asp-for="ProjectName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ProjectName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

currently when the users inputs no data the tag helper validates and outputs this default error message with The (variable name) field is required.

My question is is it possible to change the whole Text to something custom

Answer (score 0):

You can use data annotations to decorate your model properties;

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Refer: [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

Comment: Let me know why this answer is not useful?